# Instr with If statement

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong?

I want to delete certain rows if they fail to meet the criteria as provided in the code below.

I've tried Looping using the `If` statement and `Instr` function but not finding success.

```
Dim Firstrow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim Lrow As Integer
Dim celltxt As String

Firstrow = 1
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

    If InStr(Lrow, Range("ED" & Lrow), "FTOP") > 0 Then Sheets(Sheet1).Rows(Lrow).Delete

    If InStr(Lastrow, LCase(Range("DT" & Lrow)), "BB") > 0 Then Sheets(Sheet1).Rows(Lrow).Delete

    If Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(Lrow, "DX").Value = "SET" Then Sheets(Sheet1).Rows(Lrow).Delete

    If Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(Lrow, "EM").Value = "=*AAA" Then Sheets(Sheet1).Rows(Lrow).Delete

Next Lrow
```

No error messages

Comment: Do you really want `Lrow` or `Lastrow` as the first argument? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function. That said, this sounds like a use case for a filter instead of a looping row by row. And all variables declared `As Integer` should be `As Long`.

Comment: I recommend to use `Option Explicit`. `Sheets(Sheet1)` doesn't make much sense you probably meant to use `Sheets("Sheet1")`. Is there an `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code (because `Sheets(Sheet1)` should throw an error)? If so remove that line and fix the errors you get.

Comment: I need to loop from Last Row all the way up to 2nd row so that header is not deleted. Sheets(Sheet1) is because i want to use it for the first sheet and NO there is no On error resume next anywhere in the code. Can you help me where to put the On error code?

Comment: It's not a recommendation to add on error, it's an assumption you had it in as your code should be giving an error currently. Unless you have the variable Sheet1 declared containing the text string "Sheet1" it seems odd if it doesn't fail.

Comment: @TejasGoswami `Sheets(Sheet1)` is definitely wrong and cannot work, actually it should throw an error. If you mean the sheet named `Sheet1` then use `Sheets("Sheet1")`. If you mean the sheet that is at position 1 in the tab list (no matter what name it has) then use `Sheets(1)`. Please try. • If that doesn't work please [edit] your question and show the all the relevant code (this is only a part that you show). See [mcve].

Comment: Peh - Yes you're right i should be using Sheets("Sheet1") or Sheets(1). I guess that's where i'm going wrong.

Zerk - Thanks for your response. I understood what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your macro to loop through each row from the `Lastrow` to row 2, and if the value or string part is found in any of the four columns in the row, the row will be deleted. Combined all the IF statements into one using `OR`. Removed `Lrow` and `Lastrow` from the `INSTR` function, and put `AAA` into an INSTR function. `Lrow` was confusing so I removed and used `i` variable for the loop. Also added a workbook/worksheet reference variable.

```
Sub DeleteRowsThatMeetCriteria()
    'Declare your variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Set the worksheet
    Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Assign the last row varaible

        For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1 'Assign "i" as a long number to loop from the last row to row 2

        'Because you are testing different columns for different value and performing the same delete function,
        'you can combine each test using OR, so you only need one IF statement. I removed "Lrow and Lastrow" variables
        'because they were causing confusion and not needed inside the INSTR function. Since "SET" was the only full word
        'i did not change it. But I used INSTR for "AAA" since it was part of a string.

        If InStr(ws.Range("DT" & i), "BB") <> 0 _
            Or ws.Range("DX" & i).Value = "SET" _
            Or InStr(ws.Range("ED" & i), "FTOP") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(ws.Range("EM" & i), "AAA") <> 0 Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
        End If

    Next i 'DaLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed response on my Query GMalc. I have a different requirement for the below codes:

Or InStr(ws.Range("EM" & i), "AAA") <> 0 Then = The string should END WITH AAA

Or InStr(ws.Range("ED" & i), "FTOP") <> 0 = The string should START WITH FTOP.

Comment: Also just want to highlight that as per your above code each each Row is checked for DT for BB, DX for SET, ED for FTOP & EM for AAA. Instead what i want is that all Rows for Column ED should check for FTOP and delete the rest, all Rows together should be checked for DX for SET and so on.

Comment: Another thing i  have observed is that below code is deleting all the rows which contains FTOP in column ED. What i want is only retain the FTOP ones and delete the rest.

If InStr(ws.Range("ED" & i), "FTOP") <> 0

Comment: @TejasGoswami To clarify, do you only want to keep the rows that have the specific criteria in all four columns?

Comment: Below is my requirement step by step:

1. Filter Column “ED” and Delete all Rows which does not contain "FTOP".
2. Filter Column “DT” and Delete all Rows which does not contain "BB".
3. Filter Column “DX” and Delete all Rows which contains "SET".
4. Filter Column “EO” and Delete all Rows which ends with "AAA".

Comment: I want to delete the Rows that meet the criteria one by one. All the criterias should not be clubbed.